# Patch classification from large image using pytorch

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, tensor

I am using the following function to classify an image using a trained pytorch model. It works fine for a small input image.

```
def test(net, STRIDE-16, BATCH_SIZE=20, WINDOW_SIZE= (256,256)):

# Use the network on the test image
img = (1 / 255 * np.asarray(io.imread("C:/bd/R1C1.tif"), dtype='float32'))


all_preds = []

# Switch the network to inference mode
net.eval()

pred = np.zeros(img.shape[:2] + (N_CLASSES,))


for i, coords in enumerate(tqdm(grouper(batch_size, sliding_window(img, 
STRIDE, WINDOW_SIZE)))):

# Build the tensor
image_patches = [np.copy(img[x:x + w, y:y + h]).transpose((2, 0, 1)) for 
x, y, w, h in coords]

image_patches = np.asarray(image_patches)
image_patches = Variable(torch.from_numpy(image_patches).cpu(), 
volatile=True)

 # Do the inference
 outs = net(image_patches)
 outs = outs.data.cpu().numpy()

 # Fill in the results array
 for out, (x, y, w, h) in zip(outs, coords):
     out = out.transpose((1, 2, 0))
     pred[x:x + w, y:y + h] += out
  del (outs)

pred = np.argmax(pred, axis=-1)

all_preds.append(pred)


return all_preds
```

When I load a large img let say (40k x 40k) I get MemoryError. How can I avoid this memory error. Maybe by using a batch of smaller images? How to efficiently implement that?

Comment: whats the output of `image_patches.shape`?

Comment: image_patches.shape = (1, 3, 256, 256)

Comment: So image_patches which you are passing to model is already small, so how come you are getting memory error?

Comment: at this line: 

 pred = np.zeros(img.shape[:2] + (N_CLASSES,))

while initializing the array I am getting MemoryErorr as the input image has a shape (40000,40000,3)

Comment: So you are creating np array > 19GB, assuming int size 4 bytes, I'll wont create full `pred` array but save intermediate `preds` to disk, and then if required stich them together.